# amazon lambda permissions for browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-iam

I've made a few lambda functions that return html - and exposed them through a gateway function that sets the content-type to text/html - so I can browse to them.   It works great.

However - what I want is for them to only work for *me* using my current ambient amazon session.  If I expose them as public - they work, but work for everyone.  If I turn on Iam and browse there, they want an authentication token.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: *"my current ambient amazon session"* There's no such thing in any meaningful sense.  Your console session is a console session only.  Service endpoints have no sense of this "session" unless the console signs a URL for you, such as when you download an S3 object from a bucket, using the console... but S3 isn't aware of that session... only that it received a specific, valid, signed request.

Comment: hmm - that's exactly what I want - I want to use the console session - but I guess you are saying it can't be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things need to happen.

1. The API Gateway method needs to have Auth set to AWS_IAM.
2. Make sure you have the appropriate role selected in the
   configuration settings for the Lambda function.
3. The role needs to have a trust relationship associated with your
   user.
4. Make sure the IAM keys for your user (which should have appropriate Lambda privileges) are in the appropriate place on your machine.

Alternates:

1. You could also try using Cognito in the trust relationship as well to prevent hard-coding the keys in your machine.
2. Also if it is ONLY for yourself, then keeping Auth set to none in the API Gateway and generating an API key would work. Please do not use this if you are going to deploy the application anywhere. Someone could easily decompile the code and get the key. This should be purely for quick prototyping.

Comment: fundamentally I guess I'm assuming the most important constraint that I can't stash anything on the machine or browser.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is build something like a wiki - that I can access from any browser or device at any time by "logging in".  It's entirely for my own purposes, and will always be so, and I do want it to be secure.   I want it to be on lambda for a number of reasons - not least of which is for me to learn lambda.

Comment: AWS Cognito would work then. It issues temporary keys that last for a few hours after you authenticate the login provider.